# windows phone isolated storage bug

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I have tried to fix this problem

```
 if (File.Exists(data.FilePath))
 {
     AudioPlayer.Source = new Uri(data.FilePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
 }
 else
 {
     using (var storageFolder = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
     {
         using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(data.FilePath, FileMode.Open, storageFolder))
         {
             AudioPlayer.SetSource(stream);
         }
     }
 }
```

if i tap to my recorder audio it play the sound but if i tap 2 times it give me this error message:

> **IsolatedStorageException was unhandled by user code**
>
> An exception of type
> 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException occured in
> mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Operation not permitted on
> IsolatedStorageFileStream.

Comment: I'm not sure, but `File` and `IsolatedStorageFile` aren't two different thigs? Shouldn't you use `IsolatedStorageFile.FileExists`? I think that `File.Exists` generates different path (relative to app location) to `IsolatedStorageFile.Exists` (/AppData/(..)/some_relative_path).

Comment: Please put the error message into the question as text, rather than just as an image which people have to click through to and then expand in order to get anything even slightly readable... and put more effort into formatting your question before you post it.

Comment: Additionally, please tell us what `data.FilePath` is.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or **error** .... **in the question itself**

Answer (score 0):

Add this code and try to run.

```
stream.Close();
```

Comment: the stream is in a using, it will be disposed and closed.

Comment: @Mark first you have to add that code and when you set the source to audio player,at that time FileMode.open

Comment: An exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream

Comment: using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(data.FilePath, FileMode.Open, storageFolder)) this line of code

Answer (score 0):

Set Audioplayer.Source = null by default. Then try it.

Comment: AudioPlayer.Source = new Uri(data.FilePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute); Replace to null

Comment: @Viraji Shah (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(data.FilePath, FileMode.Open, storageFolder)) give me error in this line i test you're solution but didn't work